# chardet in python3 and unknown file encoding

Tags: python-3.x

I use chardet for recognize my file encoding, but this error happend :

```
fh= open("file", mode="r")
sc= chardet.detect(fh)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alireza/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    sc= chardet.detect(fh)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/chardet/__init__.py", line 24, in detect
    u.feed(aBuf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/chardet/universaldetector.py", line 65, in feed
    aLen = len(aBuf)
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

and i can't open file with out know the encoding,

```
fh= open("file", mode="r").read()
sc= chardet.detect(fh)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alireza/workspacee/makecdown/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    fh= open("910.srt", mode="r").read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 34: invalid continuation byte
```

how to use chardet without open file ?! or any way to find out file encoding after/before opening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the file like this

```
fh= open("file", mode="rb")
```

## Command Line Tool

If this does not work, try the command line tool of chardet.
Description from https://github.com/erikrose/chardet:

> chardet comes with a command-line script which reports on the
>   encodings of one or more files:
>
> ```
> % chardetect.py somefile someotherfile
> somefile: windows-1252 with confidence 0.5
> someotherfile: ascii with confidence 1.0
> ```

Comment: i use "rb" mode and it's work but chardet detect wrong encoding! MacCyrillic (confidence: 0.30) and when encode to utf8 output not useful encoding But real encoding is windows-1256 and encode to utf8 worked. is there another way to findout encoding of file and change it to utf8?

Comment: What about your files that you are trying to convert. `chardet` guesses the encoding based on the language. So if you don't have meaningful text even with to correct encoding, `chardet` might fail

Comment: i use py3 and command line tools output same with inner chardet output(first comment), chardet not work on my language(persian) with windows-1256 or arabic encoding text. thanks for u'r support.is there another way to findout encoding of file and change it to utf8?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you can find the description how it works in Python 3 here http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html. After studying that, you may find the way how to detect another specific encoding.

The code was initially derived from [Mozilla Seamonkey](http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/extensions/universalchardet/src/base/). You may find more information also there. Or look for some more advanced Python package related to Seamonkey.